how do we test published data on mqtt uisng nodered as a tester, is there any way to test it by postman with valid and invalid scenarios
I am getting this data on mqtt
{"header":{"gatewayId":"460d39e0-44c6-11ef-a75e-ff9073d46daf","assetId":"8cd3b8d8-a5db-45ef-9a1c-e812de7e5ef0","subAssetId":"11caf9ec-c6e4-4afc-9259-d08afa391d4a","version":"1.0","time":"2024-08-12T11:59:21.974Z"},"data":[{"id":"39b52fb7-3b7b-4b30-90a6-8f7cf40dcf27","value":2155.1575,"time":"2024-08-12T11:59:21.974Z"},{"id":"c6be58dc-19e8-4ea8-a30d-73de20b889fc","value":942.1393,"time":"2024-08-12T11:59:21.974Z"},{"id":"97f3a62a-bbec-4fc5-b910-6dd7d43f7d4d","value":20.4353,"time":"2024-08-12T11:59:21.974Z"}]}
{"header":{"gatewayId":"460d39e0-44c6-11ef-a75e-ff9073d46daf","assetId":"8cd3b8d8-a5db-45ef-9a1c-e812de7e5ef0","subAssetId":"c3fbfd9a-b2c0-4558-ac37-f51483aa4548","version":"1.0","time":"2024-08-12T11:59:21.974Z"},"data":[{"id":"c593d06f-3991-452c-9348-dca24d1badd1","value":1952.2536,"time":"2024-08-12T11:59:21.974Z"},{"id":"2ea1bd98-f14f-4b6c-b6d1-e62fb9e7a491","value":646.1498,"time":"2024-08-12T11:59:21.974Z"},{"id":"15593842-3841-477a-ad08-964f341274e8","value":32.719,"time":"2024-08-12T11:59:21.974Z"},{"id":"e04d6ee2-ed62-463f-b291-32c78e7374d4","value":92.5675,"time":"2024-08-12T11:59:21.974Z"},{"id":"0150a373-3ce6-4f4b-abc3-a77c581b5775","value":0.0325,"time":"2024-08-12T11:59:21.974Z"}]}
I am a beginner so dont know any idea.
need suggetion.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
